# Drone Kubernetes Runner appending CA Certificate

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, drone.io

I have a Microk8s cluster running gitea, harbor and droneci. Everything is hosted under *.dev.mydomain.com and there is a wildcard certificate for that. The certificate is signed using a private CA.

I'm trying to push the CA certificate to the Pods running the Drone CI builds such that they can push/pull from Gitea and Harbor while also being able to connect to external sources to (to fetch other docker images from dockerhub for example).

DroneCI and the drone runner are installed using Helm. I have tried the following in the `values.yaml` file for the runner:

```
DRONE_RUNNER_VOLUMES: "/sslcerts:/etc/ssl/certs"
```

This overwrites the `/etc/ssl/certs/` folder in the runner pod. Any requests made from the pod to harbor or gitea work, any requests to anything else fail with error `x509 certificate signed by unknown authority`

I also tried

```
DRONE_RUNNER_VOLUMES: "/sslcerts/ca-certificates.crt:/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt"
```

This returned the error `mounting "/sslcerts/ca-certificates.crt" to rootfs at "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt" caused: mount through procfd: not a directory: unknown"`

Any ideas on how to go about what I'm trying to do? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As the runners are Alpine Linux based all you should have to do is to mount your certificates in the `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/` folder (*not* in a subfolder but right into that folder).
Alpine should then add all certificates from there to `/etc/ssl/certs` for you.